# intentservice has uid of 1000 from one android account but different uid for another user account

Tags: android, intentservice, uid

I have created an intentservice that is signed with system certs so it can have system privs and run as system. I put it in /system/app directory. When it is invoked by my application running under "Owner" account on android 4.4.2 it has the uid of 1000:

I/ActivityManager( 3223): Start proc com.abc.dbintentservice for service com.abc.dbintentservice/.DbIntentService: pid=4515 uid=1000 gids={41000, 1028, 1015, 1023, 3002, 3001, 3003}

and it has no problem opening an sqlite file with system ownership.

I created a secondary user profile and installed the same app that invokes the intentservice and I get a different uid

I/ActivityManager( 3227): Start proc com.abc.dbintentservice for service com.abc.dbintentservice/.DbIntentService: pid=5161 uid=1001000 gids={41000, 1028, 1015, 1023, 3002, 3001, 3003}

and the intentservice has a uid that cannot open the sqlite file.

Any insight is appreciated.

Comment: Where is this file? Each user account gets its own portion of internal storage and external storage.

Comment: it is a file that I put in /data/ (because it was a system owned file)

Comment: If you mean literally in `/data/` (e.g., `/data/foo.db`), then that's your problem. If your objective is a single database for all users, I don't know how to do that, even for system apps, though there may be a solution. If your objective is for each user to have their own database, use standard locations (e.g., `getFilesDir()`), as with any other Android app.

Comment: I did mean literally /data/foo.db. I guess the puzzler is the first "Owner" account had the intentservice run with uid 1000 (and all the apps that made use of the intentservice had no problem under the first account) but the second account did not. The purpose for the intentservice with system privs was the ability for apps to have the intentservice query the file on their behalf